# AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'create_ExternalLink'

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with the module core.py, it's written based on versions that are not compatible with mine.

So what I'm doing is editing lines such as openFile to open_file.

As I'm continuing, I cannot solve this problem, how am I supposed to edit the line to continue?

Error log:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spikedetekt\core.py", line 141, in 
spike_d
etection_from_raw_data
main_h5.create_ExternalLink(shank_group['main', i], 'waveforms',
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'create_ExternalLink'
```

core.py:

```
# spikedetekt data for main file, and links to waveforms
for i in probe.shanks_set:
    shank_table['spikedetekt', i] = main_h5.create_table(shank_group['main', i],
        'spikedetekt', shank_description(len(probe.channel_set[i])))
    main_h5.create_ExternalLink(shank_group['main', i], 'waveforms', 
                               shank_table['waveforms', i])
```

Comment: Is that PyTables? If it is, try `create_external_link` and refer to [the list of changes](http://www.pytables.org/MIGRATING_TO_3.x.html#api-name-changes) in the documentation for other substitutions.

Comment: thanks! the link you gave me is a great help!

Comment: One thing I only noticed after commenting is that they mention the `pt2to3` tool to make the migration automatic.